# Counting Number of Suit in a Hand

Tags: java, oop

this is an assignment question and I have tried to search online but seems like no one else is doing it. Given the following, each row represents a card hand:

```
SQ S7 S4 HT H9 DQ D7 D6 CT CA C8 C7 C2
ST SJ S2 HK HJ HA H7 H5 H4 H3 DJ D2 C6
SK S8 S6 S5 H2 DK DA D9 D8 D4 CQ C9 C3
SA S9 S3 HQ H8 H6 DT D5 D3 CK CJ C5 C4
```

I need to count the number of spades, hearts, diamonds and clubs in each row. In my program, I have a Suit and Rank enum class, an object of Card constructed and store in an ArrayList. The end result should look like this:

```
SQ S7 S4 HT H9 DQ D7 D6 CT CA C8 C7 C2
3 2 3 5
ST SJ S2 HK HJ HA H7 H5 H4 H3 DJ D2 C6
3 7 2 1
SK S8 S6 S5 H2 DK DA D9 D8 D4 CQ C9 C3
4 1 5 3
SA S9 S3 HQ H8 H6 DT D5 D3 CK CJ C5 C4
3 3 3 4
```

The assignment want us to explore the use of a MyInt class to find (or I believe, store) the number:

```
class MyInt
{
   private int n;

   public int getInt()
   {
       return n;
   }

   public void setInt(int n)
   {
       this.n = n;
   }
}
```

handInfo method is in the main method and I believe I am suppose to fill in here to count the number of suit per row:

```
private static void handInfo(String [] aHand, MyInt s, MyInt h, MyInt d, MyInt c)
{
    // count of suit per row here?
}
```

If I think about it, it is likely that I need to count the alphabet of each card to count the number of suit. I have no idea where to start. I am also confused by the purpose of an array called aHand.

Will appreciate for some guidance or help.

Thank you.

Comment: You said: "each row represents a card hand". And a row looks like this: `SQ S7 S4 HT H9 DQ D7 D6 CT CA C8 C7 C2`. So I think we can safely assume that the variable `aHand`, which is an array of Strings, is supposed to contain every cars in a hand, i.e. every substring in the row of text, i.e. "SG", "S7", "S4", etc. So you need to **split** (this is a hin: read the javadoc) each row of text to produce an array containing these strings.

Comment: Don't search the internet for a solution to your assignment. That's not how an assignment is supposed to be done. Do it yourself. By reasonin bout what you need to do. By doing it yourself, on paper or in your head first. By reading the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are given an array of strings and you need to check what letter each string starts with and update the appropriate `MyInt`.

Each string could start with either `S` for spade, `C` for club, `D` for diamond or `H` for hearts.

```
private static void handInfo(String [] hand, MyInt spadeCount, MyInt heartCount, MyInt diamondCount, MyInt clubCount)
{
    // count of suit per row here?
}
```

You are supposed to write code inside the above method that fills this information in.

You can examine each card in the `hand` by using a loop:

```
for (String card: hand) {
    ... // Do something with the card
}
```

In the place where it says to *do something* is where you have to check what letter the card starts with and then get the count for the appropriate `MyInt` and update it.

For example, *if* the card starts with `S`, you have to get the count from `MyInt spadeCount`, and update that number by adding `1` to it.

```
int countSpade = spadeCount.getInt();
countSpade += 1;
spadeCount.setInt(countSpade);
```

Comment: Thank you for the guidance! I will try it out.

Comment: Marking this as the answer as it provides a guideline on how to tackle my issue.

Answer (score 0):

> SQ S7 S4 HT H9 DQ D7 D6 CT CA C8 C7 C2
>
> I need to count the number of spades, hearts, diamonds and clubs in each row.

So you just need to find out the number of 'S', 'H', 'D' and 'C' in a given string.

Simple way would be to just interate over all characters in the string. If it's an 'S', increment the spades-count, if it's a 'H', increment the hearts-count etc.